# Insert row SQL Server affecting datatime field, using VB .NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net, insert

I' m trying to insert a row in a database residing on SQL Server. I'm using VB .NET and the ADO .NET framework. 
The structure of the table I want affect is shown below:

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
  [UserName] [nvarchar](80) NOT NULL,
  [Description] [nvarchar](600) NULL,
  [IDCategory] [int] NULL,
  [RegistrationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [CategoryFlag] [bit] NULL,
  [TypeFlag] [bit] NULL,
   ...
```

I have implemented this, with the following code:

```
 <WebMethod()> _
   Sub insertElement()
     Dim conn As SqlConnection
     Dim sqlcmd As SqlCommand
     Dim res As Integer

     conn = New SqlConnection(Utilities.ConnectionString)
     sqlcmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
     sqlcmd.Connection = conn
     sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
     sqlcmd.CommandText = "insert into Users (UserName, RegistrationDate) values (@user, @date)"
     Dim param As SqlParameter
     param = New SqlParameter("@user", "myself")
     sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(param)
     param = New SqlParameter("@date", '2012/10/11 20:30:15')
     sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(param)

     Try
        conn.Open()
        res = sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        sqlcmd.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

Utilities.ConnectionString is just a class created by me for retuning the ConnectionString associated to my database.

I have tried to do something like this, without affecting any datatime filed and it worked.
But with the above code there is probably a mistake in datatime management, because it does not work.
Someone can help me?

Comment: so, what is wrong then...? What does or does not happen?

Comment: then please edit your question and add that line

Comment: The table "Users" on my database is not affected from the insert. But no error returns!

Comment: What is the exception, anyway? Remove the `catch` block and please post the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how this row

```
param = New SqlParameter("@date", '2012/10/11 20:30:15')
```

does even compile, but I guess it should read

```
param = New SqlParameter("@date", CDate("2012/10/11 20:30:15", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

using a `DateTime` value instead of a `string`.

I think you just swallow the exception by using an empty `catch` block.

---

Nonetheless, you are better off using the `using` statement:

```
using conn = New SqlConnection(Utilities.ConnectionString), sqlcmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
    sqlcmd.Connection = conn
    sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    ...
    res = sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

which will automatically close/dispose your connection etc.

Comment: I solved the problem: was related to a FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT. 
So the above code it is correct. @BigYellowCactus I don't now why but it is working using even the statement:
param = New SqlParameter("@date", '2012/10/11 20:30:15')